# Keep jquery dropdown menu open after opening another page of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a dropdown menu by mouse click. When I click on the some "dropdown link", another page of my website is opening but the menu is closed. I need to keep it open and actual "dropdown link" should be shown in bold.

Here is an example of what I have http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry313/dfgjx22j/1/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="click1" class="clickme">Click me 1</a>
<ul id="menu_list" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
</ul>
<br><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clickme">Click me 2</a>
<ul style="display:none">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here I have a  redirect to another page of website:

```
<li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggleClick = function(){
        var divObj = $(this).next();
        var nstyle = divObj.css("display");

        if(nstyle == "none"){
            divObj.slideDown(false,function(){
                $("html").bind("click",function(){
                    $("html").unbind("click");
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            divObj.slideUp(true,function(){
                $("html").bind("click",function(){
                    $("html").unbind("click");
                });
            });
        }
    };
    $(".clickme").click(toggleClick);
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The fiddle you have provided, the drop down menu remains displayed after opening another page. I can't see the problem if this is the desired result?

Comment: @Vector: Same confusion here. I guess he wants the `dropdownlist` to be opened on the new page.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Yes, I need all "drop down links" to be open on the new page

Comment: perhaps an up-vote as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your external dropdown link href an extra hashtag **parameter**

```
<a id="dropdown-id" href="http://www.yourpage/#dropdown-link-name">Dropdown link</a>
```

Also give your dropdownlink a unique id

Give the dropdown ul also a unique id name

```
<ul id="sub-level-1" style="display:none">
```

When the new page loads, check if the url contains the text #dropdown-link-name, and if it does, set the style of the dropdown element to display:block

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#dropdown-link-name") > -1) {
        $('#dropdown-class-name').closest("#sub-level-1").css("display","block");
    }
});
```

In this way you have to make a new jquery ready function for every submenu block. I can't give you a jsfiddle, but I tested this locally and it works.