# Keep dropdown menu open after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this side menu, each item with sub-items, that when clicked go to another page. [image]

[image]

When I press the sub-item News of MAIN and I load another page, the menu collapses like in the first photo. Is there any way to keep the menu open when navigating to other pages. This below is my HTML code. I've been stuck for two days with this problem. I've tried options from similar questions here but no luck. I'm fairly new to front-end development, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="main-menu" class="main-menu collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-home"></i>Home </a></li>
                <h3 class="menu-title">L&amp;D</h3><!-- /.menu-title -->
                <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>MAIN</a>
                    <ul id="navigation" class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'news' %}">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'sport' %}">Sport</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'lifestyle' %}">Lifestyle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'economy' %}">Economy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'politics' %}">Politics</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-bolt"></i>ABOUT</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'authors' %}">Authors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'history' %}">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'trivia' %}">Trivia</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Would it be a possibility to hard code it into the pages you want it to appear on?

Comment: What solutions did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: @McMuffin No that is not possible since every page inherits from the base page, which contains the left menu.

Comment: @PlarentHaxhidauti you could copy the menu into these pages

Comment: @NawedKhan I tried the answers from this question but couldn't make it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088145/keep-jquery-dropdown-menu-open-after-opening-another-page-of-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = location.href;

$('.sub-menu').each(function() {
    var $dropdownmenu = $(this);
    $(this).find('li').each(function() {
        if( $(this).find('a').attr('href')== url ) {
            console.log( $dropdownmenu ); // this is your dropdown menu which you want to display
            console.log($($dropdownmenu).parents('li')); // this is the parent list item of the dropdown menu. Add collapse class or whatever that collapses its child list
        }
    });
});
```

This code will help

*Modified

Comment: on the line you put a comment I put, $(".sub-menu").closest("ul").addClass("show");  but still not getting the result I want. Could you please guide me on this.

Comment: Thank you, your first answer already helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can save the "status" of menu on a cookie or on session, like a snapshot and read it when you are loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

When each main list item is expanded, it has a `show` class added.  You could check what URL the user is going to, and if it's under that submenu, pass that into the list items classlist via your templating engine.  It would look something like

`<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown {% if showClass %}show{% endif %}">`

And resolve to

`<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown show">`

Thus being expanded on the next page.

---

Edit: The same class needs to be added to the `<ul>` element below the parent `<li>`, i.e.

`<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown {% if showClass %}show{% endif %}">`

...
`<ul id="navigation" class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu {% if showClass %}show{% endif %}">`

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript find the anchor that's URL matches the current URL and then toggle it's parent's visibility.

Obviously, you will need to tweak for your specific needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     //var current_url = window.location.href;
     var current_url = "news";
     $(".sub-menu").find("a[href='" + current_url + "']").closest("ul").addClass("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu" class="main-menu collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-home"></i>Home </a></li>
                <h3 class="menu-title">L&amp;D</h3><!-- /.menu-title -->
                <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>MAIN</a>
                    <ul id="navigation" class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="news">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'sport' %}">Sport</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'lifestyle' %}">Lifestyle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'economy' %}">Economy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'politics' %}">Politics</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-bolt"></i>ABOUT</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'authors' %}">Authors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'history' %}">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'trivia' %}">Trivia</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Wont hiding it via jquery break the menu since it operates on the `show` class being present? I think you would want to remove the `show` class with a solution like this

Comment: @Bryan I should have mentioned the "hide" part was more to prove its working. I'm not sure what exact method was being used to toggle visibility. For clarity, I'm going to change it.